# How to persistence firebase auth in electron js?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, electron

how to persistence firebase auth in electron js, so when re open the electron js no need to login again.

currently i implement login process in main process but auth.currentUser will get null if re open the app

login in main process

```
auth.setPersistence(browserLocalPersistence);
const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, authLogin.email, authLogin.password);
```

how to detect is login or not

```
ipcMain.on("get-current-user", async (_event) => (_event.returnValue = auth?.currentUser?.toJSON() || null));
```

detect onAuthStateChanged in main process

```
authRepository.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (!!user) {
            // logic for subscribe functions
        }
        else {
            // logic for unsubscribe functions
        }
    });
```